# Ramda and Typescript: add missing typings

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I use TypeScript and Ramdajs in my current project. And I've just realized that some typings are missed, i.e. there is no typing for `innerJoin` function ( @types/ramda version is 0.25.36, latest as I guest right now).
I've tried to add custom definitions in a separate file within the project:

```
declare namespace R {
    interface Static {
        innerJoin(): any;
    }
}
```

and even:

```
declare let R: R.Static;

declare namespace R {
    interface Static {
        innerJoin(): any; /* here should be a specific signature */
    }
}

export = R;
export as namespace R;
```

but without success - typescript marks `R.innerJoin(/*...*/)` as unknown:

> Property 'innerJoin' does not exist on type 'Static'

Does someone know how to implement it correctly?
I found a workaround: `const R_innerJoin = (R as any).innerJoin`
But I suspect that there should be more elegant solution using '.d.ts' ...

P.S. ramda version is 0.25.0 if this matters.

**Update**

I'm using Ramda this way:

```
import * as R from 'ramda';
const myFn = (a, b) => R.innerJoin(// etc
```

Comment: In your code that uses `R`, are you importing it or using the global?  If you're using the global, you may be running into the [issues with augmenting UMD globals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12106).  The easiest thing may be to make a modified copy of the ramda typings for your project.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, updated the question's body. I'm using ramda via imports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are importing the `R` namespace from the module, you must augment the original module.  If you declare your own `R` namespace, at best you'll see either your namespace or the imported one, not a merger.  The following is working for me after a little trial and error:

```
declare module "dummy" {
    module "ramda" {
        interface Static {
            innerJoin(): any;
        }
    }
}
```

The outer module declaration is needed to make the inner module declaration an "augmentation" instead of shadowing the original module, as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-338785578).  That trick is unfortunately not properly documented AFAIK.